# Cannot invoke expressions whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm receiving a type error when using an adapter as in this reduced example (see last line of method `getGloryOfAnimal`). I'm puzzled because, as far as I can tell, the types are fully explicated.

```
interface ICheetah {
    pace: string;
}

interface ILion {
    mane: string;
}

let LionAdapter = {
    endpoint: 'lion',
    castRawData: (d: any) => d as ILion,
    getValue: (d: ILion) => d.mane
}

let CheetahAdapter = {
    endpoint: 'cheetah',
    castRawData: (d: any) => d as ICheetah,
    getValue: (d: ICheetah) => d.pace
}

type AnimalAdapter = typeof CheetahAdapter | typeof LionAdapter;

function getDataFromEndpoint(endpoint: string): any {
    // data comes back in a format from the server
    // synchronous here for simplicity
    if (endpoint === 'cheetah') {
        return {
            pace: 'lightning speed'
        };
    } else {
        return {
            mane: 'shiny mane'
        };
    }
}

function getGloryOfAnimal(adapter: AnimalAdapter): string {
    let data = adapter.castRawData(getDataFromEndpoint(adapter.endpoint));
    // type error below:
    // 'cannot invoke expression whose type lacks a call signature'
    return adapter.getValue(data); 
}

console.log(getGloryOfAnimal(LionAdapter));
```

I believe I could write an interface for the two adapters rather than creating a union type (e.g. `(T | U)`), but in my case the interface would be very large.

Thoughts? Am I stuck with creating a huge common interface for the adapters?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the type of `adapter.getValue` is:

```
((d: ICheetah) => string) | ((d: ILion) => string)
```

And this type indeed lacks a call signature.

The type of `data` is:

```
ICheetah | ILion
```

Which would have helped if the type of `adapter.getValue` would have been:

```
(d: ICheetah | ILion) => string
```

My questions is why don't you use classes? Then the actual functions will be class methods in which the type is known.

---

#### Edit

You can get around this error with doing:

```
let LionAdapter = {
    endpoint: 'lion',
    getValue: (d: any) => d.mane
}

let CheetahAdapter = {
    endpoint: 'cheetah',
    getValue: (d: any) => d.pace
}

function getGloryOfAnimal(adapter: AnimalAdapter): string {
    return adapter.getValue(getDataFromEndpoint(adapter.endpoint)); 
}
```

Which also removes the need for the `castRawData`.
If you still want type safety then replace `d` to `(d as ICheetah)`.

Comment: I have the same issue if I make the adapters like this: 

`class CheetahAdapter {
    endpoint: 'cheetah';
    castRawData (d: any) { return d as ICheetah}
    getValue (d: ICheetah) { return d.pace; }
}`

Am I misunderstanding your meaning?

Comment: Perhaps you're suggesting they should inherit from a common abstract class? That's difficult in my context since there a many endpoints that overlap in various ways. I would like to use the adapters in various cases where I know a subset of those adapters satisfy the necessary conditions.

Comment: I can't say I understand what you're trying to do, so I can't help you more than with a workaround, for which check my revised answer. If you can explain more then maybe a better solution can be found